# Why am I getting a babel errors from a .babelrc file in a parent directory

Tags: babeljs, next.js

I was recently trying to debug errors in a next.js getting started project and realized that it didn't like a .babelrc file in a parent directory.

My questions are:

1. Why is the project throwing an error on a .babelrc configuration file in a parent directory that's not part of the project?  Does it recursively look for a babel configuration file in all parent directories or did I at some point configure babel to look at that config file?  How can I check what that configuration is?
2. Is this a quirk of next.js that makes it look for a configuration file in a parent directory?

I forgot if I had added that .babelrc configuration in the parent directory - is that something that I needed?  What is the configuration?  How should I update it to make the error go away?

```
ERROR in ./pages/index.js

Module build failed: ReferenceError: [BABEL] /Users/me/Projects/foo/foo-web/pages/index.js: 
 Using removed Babel 5 option: /Users/me/Projects/.babelrc.optional 
 - Put the specific transforms you want in the `plugins` option
```

.babelrc

```
"optional": ["es7.classProperties"]
```

Answer (score 0):

1. babel is looking first .babelrc file is present in the root directory
2. you have to create the .babelrc file

**npm install  babel-plugin-transform-runtime**

insert to .babelrc

```
{
  "plugins": [
    "transform-runtime"
  ]
}
```

[more info](http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-runtime/)

Comment: but is it default behavior to go to a parent directory outside of the app?